# Python Mutiple Lists into multiple lists to deconflict

Tags: python, arcmap

Let me rephrase this,

My Code:

To avoid coping all my code again print SpaceTree gives us (A:B:C:A:C:D) for each line of data.

```
 SkyTree = [SpaceTree.split(':') for x in SpaceTree]
```

Gives me this:

```
[[u'A', u'B', u'C', u'A', u'C', u'D'], [u'A', u'B', u'C', u'A', u'C', u'D'], [u'A', u'B', u'C', u'A', u'C', u'D'], [u'A', u'B', u'C', u'A', u'C', u'D'], [u'A', u'B', u'C', u'A', u'C', u'D'], [u'A', u'B', u'C', u'A', u'C', u'D'], [u'A', u'B', u'C', u'A', u'C', u'D'], [u'A', u'B', u'C', u'A', u'C', u'D'], [u'A', u'B', u'C', u'A', u'C', u'D'], [u'A', u'B', u'C', u'A', u'C', u'D'], [u'A', u'B', u'C', u'A', u'C', u'D']]
```

Now I need to take that hot mess and turn it into

```
[[A:B:C:D], [A:B:C:D], [A:B:C:D], [A:B:C:D], [A:B:C:D], [A:B:C:D]]
```

... so that I can put it into a spreadsheet like this

```
Spreadsheet 1                      Spreadsheet 2              Master Final Sheet

Trees   Location   Birds       Trees Location     Birds           Trees  Location    Birds
1A        A,B      A:B:C       1A    A,B          A:D:C           1A        A,B    A:B:C:D
2B        A,B      C:A:B       2B    A,B          A:B:D           2B        A,B    A:B:C:D
3C        A,B      C:B:A       3C    A,B          D:B:C           3C        A,B    A:B:C:D
```

BUT this will be used on tens of thousands of lines of data. It will also have certain feilds like Tree height, Bird Color, ect.

Comment: You should have used something else instead of Trees. Now I look at the code and think you have [trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure%29) everywhere.

Comment: I hate to be *that guy*, but I think you'd be better off using a relational DBMS or sqlite.

Comment: `SkyTree = [SpaceTree.split(':') for x in SpaceTree]` makes no sense. All you're doing is splitting the same `SpaceTree` string over and over again. All this gets you is a big list of lists with the same sublist repeated over and over again.

Comment: @NullUserException i input what you put, it is giving me [u'A', u'B', u'C', u'D']. Why are the "u's" there? Also, will it still do this to all the rows of data, or is it deduping every row, and not wwhat is in the list. i want each thing in brackets deduped on itself, not all list against all lists.

Comment: @NullUserException How do i get it to reference every line in my table then?

Comment: Say what? The `u`s just tell you it's a unicode string; it's not actually part of the data. For example, if you have a list `a = [u'A', u'B', u'C', u'D']`, `print(':'.join(a))` will give you `A:B:C:D`

Comment: Thats amazing, i'm sorry i am very new to python, i started teaching myself it on Monday. So now that i have it formated correctly, how do i input this new data. along with the spreadsheets from  before, into a new table?

Comment: Well, how did you load the original spreadsheet? If you used a library, they must have some way of outputting data as well.